# How do I create groups and count IDs in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, grouping

I need help with writing some SQL code.
I have a table organized like the following.

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Jill | drug |
| Jill | alc |
| Matt | drug |
| Sally | drug |
| Max | alc |
| Millie | other |
| Rob | drug |

I need to count how many people (name) are designated to drug only, how many are designated to alc only, and how many are drug and alc. Output should look like:

| code | Count |
| --- | --- |
| drug | 3 |
| alc | 1 |
| drug & alc | 1 |

So Millie wouldn't be included in these counts bc I just want to look at drug and alc for the code.

Please help I can't figure it out!!

Answer (score 0):

First look at persons. What are they addicted to? This results in a string of addictions per person, just as shown in your requested result. Then count the persons for all found addiction strings.

```
select addictions, count(*)
from
(
  select name, group_concat(code order by code separator '&') as addictions
  from mytable
  where code in ('drug', 'alc')
  group by name
) per_name
group by addictions
order by addictions;
```

I have limited this to 'drug' and 'alc' as requested. You can remove this limit by removing the where clause, if you like.